# Long poll client side framework

Tags: javascript, ajax, long-polling

I've been looking for a solution all morning (for my boss) and can't really find much. The server has already implemented long polling and I can make requests and get responses from it just fine with an ajax request.

However, I'm looking for a javascript framework that I guess wraps the functionality of long polling. I'm not really a web guy, so I might be over thinking what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try [socket.io](http://socket.io/) and just enable the ajax long polling transport.

Comment: Will this work if I only use it on the client and don't have a `socket.io` implementation on the server?

Comment: That I haven't tried. I suspect that it won't work with a generic AJAX server, but you might be able to make use of portions of the client side code or at least look at the long polling client code for ideas.